# MuleRequester error while using it inside my flow

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, mule, mule-studio

My muleRequester Config:

```
  <mulerequester:config name="Mule_Requester" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
```

My flow Config:
Flow('Y'):

```
  <flow>
 <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file://D:/Sample/Folder" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
    <logger message="just logging after datamapper #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  .
  .
  .
</flow>
```

**Error I am getting:**

schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document    'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mule-mulerequester.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mulerequester:config'. One of '{http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans:beans,

```
  .
  .
  .
```

}' is expected.

Please help me out in this issue.Cann't I use muleRequester in the beginning of flow(flow'Y')?? i cannot use file connector, as it polls the file from the resource folder, before the file is completely written by the file producer(flow'X').

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the `<file:inbound-endpoint>` with the `fileAge` attribute in flow'Y'. Using this attribute forces mule to wait on flow'X' to complete its work. Something like the following:

`<file:inbound-endpoint path="D:/Sample/Folder" fileAge="1000" moveToDirectory="D:/Sample/Folder/backup"/>`

Comment: No, we are not sure how much time flow'X' takes to write the file.

Comment: It is used to write large file greater 80 mb of size. so it would not be correct approach

Comment: The fileAge means that mule will start processing the file if no other processes touched it for 1000 milliseconds. So it does not matter how big your file is. Give it a try and let me know, you won't be disappointed.

Comment: Sure will let you know once I try it.